# Laravel Eloquent - Get a specific row and others

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In my users table i want to get admin user and the others who are activated. 
in fact the result that I want is concatenation of this two query result :

```
User::where('user_name','admin')->first();
User::where('is_active',1)->get();
```

is there any way to get this result in one query?

Comment: here you have to pass one variable than you take when condition to write query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = User::where('is_active',1)->where('user_name','admin')->first();
```

Above Query will give you only one Active User whos user_name is admin and active.

As per my understanding from your question you want all users who are "active" and whos user_name is "admin" then try this below query.

```
$query = User::where('is_active',1)->orWhere('user_name','admin')->get();
```

Hope this may solve your problem.

Comment: the result of this query is only admin user

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Union to put the two result sets together.

```
$first = User::where('user_name','admin')->first();
$users = User::where('is_active',1)->union($first)->get();
```

That should get you the first Admin user AND all the active users.

In fact, as they are on the same table, a OR should also work like below:

```
$users = User::where('is_active',1)
             ->orWhere('user_name', 'admin')
             ->get();
```

I'll leave both parts in as both will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
  User::where('is_active',1)
       ->orWhere('user_name', 'admin')
       ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
 $rsltUser = User::where('is_active',1)
       ->orWhere('user_name', 'admin')
       ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply everybody missed the `laravel` out of box `method which accepts array`

```
Eloquent Version
User::where(['user_name' => 'admin','is_active' => '1'])->first();
```

Another Method

```
DB Facade Version

DB::table('users')->where(['user_name' => 'admin','is_active' => '1'])->first();
```

Hope its helps